# $_POST not working.it ain't producing any values

Tags: php

```
<?php
$query = "Select * from users where username = '$user' ";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$test = $_POST['test1'];
$ques = "Select * from questions where testname = '$test' ";
$qres = mysql_query($ques) or die(mysql_error());
$qdetails = mysql_fetch_array($qres);
$id = $qdetails['id'];
$testname = $qdetails['testname'];
$ans = "Select * from answers where qid = $id";
$ares = mysql_query($ans) or die(mysql_error());
if($qdetails) {
?>
<div class="padding">

 <form name="answerform" action="answer.php" method="GET">
<h3>&nbsp;</h3>
<input name="test2" id="test2"  type="text" value="<?php echo $qdetails['testname'];?>" /><h3><?php echo $qdetails['text'];?></h3>
 <input name="test3" id="test3"  type="text" value="<?php echo $qdetails['testseries'];?>" /><h3><?php echo $qdetails['text'];?></h3>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<?php while($opdetails = mysql_fetch_assoc($ares)) { ?>
<input class="text" id="opt2" name="correctans" type="radio" value="<?php echo $opdetails['text']; ?>" /><br /><?php echo $opdetails['text']; ?>  <?php }?>
<div class="two-fields clearfix".
<p class="confirm">&nbsp;</p>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT ANSWER" />
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

THIS IS answer.php and here I try to post information from test2 and test3 fields but I am not getting any output
the output shows blank array()
and unidentified index test2
and unidentified index test3
I am not able to figure out the error

Answer (score 4):

At no point in the code do you even access the POST values of `test2` or `test3` only `test1` which isn't even in your form. Check for `$_POST['test2']` and `$_POST['test3']`

Comment: hey i am really sorry...i posted the same code 2wice..i have corrected it...plz view it again and provide me with some help...i really appericiate your efforts...thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

You are submitting fields using get

```
method="GET"
```

And you SHOULD get the informatiosn trough $_GET['example']; !!!

**Example**

```
<form method="post" action="action.php"> 
    text:<input type="text" size =40 name="name"> 
    <input type=submit value="Submit Post"> 
    </form>
```

That code inserted into a html page (on the body) represent a form. That form have just one indication, the "text:" and a input where you can put content. When the user is satisfy of its content, he can push the "submit" button (that is representated by the input type = submit in the example). When he press that button, the information included in the input will be give to action.php and that page (coded in the action="action.php") is launched.

Now, in the code of action.php, for example :

```
<?php echo "The text that you put in the box is : ".$_POST['name']; ?>
```

If you want to pass the informations trough the URL, you should use GET methods.

```
<form method="get" action="action.php"> 
    text:<input type="text" size =40 name="name"> 
    <input type=submit value="Submit Post"> 
    </form>
```

and in action.php :

```
<?php echo "The text that you put in the box is : ".$_GET['name']; ?>
```

I hope that example will open your eyes ;-)

++

Comment: thanks for replying.....but i still have a problem  i have done <form name="answerform" action="answer.php" method="GET"> and then in answer.php   $test = $_GET['test2'];   &    $tester = $_GET['test3']; as you suggested...but still i am getting the same error  "Undefined index: test2"   &    "Undefined index: test3"....plz help

Comment: @rag : And when you submit your form , can you paste here the URL that is called??? please

Comment: i am working in my localhost only so the url is http://localhost/scholars/answer.php

Comment: @rag : ok, so it is not answer.php but the form that is not good. So can you paste me the html that is showed in your browser? Show>Option for developers>Code source in Chrome of the index page? It will show me the HTML page with the form (not the php) Thx

Comment: and you can try without the "input class="text" id="opt2" name="correctans" type="radio" ...

Comment: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0BxVShUQnK1p8MGRiY2EwMjYtZTJjNC00NDNiLTk5OTItZDljNDgzZGQ2ODZl         this is the file question.php                                           https://docs.google.com/open?id=0BxVShUQnK1p8ZjgyYTczM2YtNmE4My00NDEyLWI2MzUtYjQ2NTA3MjFjYmU3      and this is the file answer.php   including the html code...i hope this helps to find the solution...and thanks again for looking into my problem and giving your time

Comment: u will have to download it by clicking on the download button on top right

Comment: please paste the url that's called when you push the submit button, we will see the arguments of the get

Comment: even with get as the method i only get http://localhost/scholars/answer.php in my url on clicking the submit button

Comment: ok and can I see the code executed into your browser (show>code in you browser) or host the script in a webserver to see it running of myself?

Answer (score 1):

Change the form method to 'post'.

```
<form name="answerform" action="answer.php" method="POST">
```

Comment: i have edited the form...plz check it again ..it wasnt wrking with post so i had to do it with get

Comment: in your `answer.php` did you try print_r($_POST) when the form `method="POST"`?

Comment: yaa i got an empty array only